# How to document a JS class in Typescript with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I have a codebase that I'm looking to slowly migrate to Typescript. This means I create classes the non-ES6 way using [`util.inherits`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) from Node, and would like to use JSDoc type annotations rather than converting to Typescript at this time.

But I'm having a problem typing classes:

```
var util = require("util");

function Base() {
}

/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} arg
 */
function Thing(arg) {
    Thing.super_.call(this);

    this.x = arg;
}

util.inherits(Thing, Base);

var thing = new Thing("test");
```

When running Typescript gives the following output:

```
$ tsc --noEmit --allowJs --checkJs .\test.js
test.js:11:15 - error TS2339: Property 'super_' does not exist on type 'typeof Thing'.

11         Thing.super_.call(this);
                 ~~~~~~
```

Is there a way to document the `super_` property created by `inherits` using JSDoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
/** @type {typeof Base} */
Thing.super_;
```